# MurmurHash3_32 Java returns negative numbers

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, hash, murmurhash

I am trying to replicate the file hashing of MobileSheetsPro, an Android app, where there is a hashcodes.txt which includes a hash for each file, as well as the path, last modified date and filesize. We'll just focus on the hashing part.

So for the random song I uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tfldoystki7yjj/Are%20You%20Lonesome%20Tonight_.jpg?dl=0) if you want to try it for yourself, I am using the `murmurhash-native` npm package to convert it to a buffer and then hash it like so:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { murmurHash } = require("murmurhash-native");
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

async function hashcodeObjFromFilePath(filepath) {
    const buf = await readFileAsync(filepath);
    const h = murmurHash(buf);
    console.log(h);
}
```

This prints out a hash of `4275668817` when using the default seed of 0 and `3020822739` when using the seed `0xc58f1a7b` as a second argument.

The problem: the app seems to calculate it differently. The developer wrote the following, but I don't see that exact function in the code he linked:

> Check this out: [github link](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava/src/com/google/common/hash)
>
> Those are the classes I've utilized. I call
>   Hashing.goodFast32Hash(HASH_KEY)) where HASH_KEY is equal to
>   0xC58F1A7B.

**EDIT** I've got more infos from the dev:

> I call Files.hash(file, Hashing.goodFast32Hash(HASH_KEY)); Using the
>   return value from that, I call "asInt()" on the HashCode object that
>   is returned. So it's a signed integer value (negative values are just
>   fine). And yes, HASH_KEY is the seed value passed to the function.

Since I'm not good at Java I still have no idea to replicate this in node-js...

That's all the info I have, folks.
Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! The asInt() function in the Java lib returns a signed int32 ***in little endian byte order**

The following is probably not the easiest way but the code

```
const h = murmurHash(buf, "buffer", 0xc58f1a7b);
// console.log(parseInt(h, 16).toString(2));
const fromHashFile = Buffer.alloc(4);
fromHashFile.writeInt32BE(-1274144557);
console.log(fromHashFile);
console.log(h);
console.log(h.readInt32BE());
console.log("hash from hashcodes file: -1274144557");
```

Prints out the following to console:

```
<Buffer b4 0e 18 d3>
<Buffer b4 0e 18 d3>
-1274144557
hash from hashcodes file: -1274144557
```